# Update the game-engine tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to open an... Open... Discussion... <sup>Damnit I said that twice!</sup>

We often get questions about third party engines, some based on Blender like Armory/UPBGE, some completely unrelated like Unity/UE. Yet they are frequently tagged as `game-engine` like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304087/how-can-i-make-that-4-key-movement-to-effect-only-the-bone-and-act-as-if-the-bon).
In other words: we get questions related in different ways to game engines as a whole or specific game engines, that are almost all tagged as `game-engine` with no proper alternatives.

But as per the `game-engine` description:

> The (BGE) Blender Game Engine (discontinued, blender 2.41 - 2.79) allows you to create interactive 3D applications, game prototypes and simulations.

Besides, I think it would be interesting to have more detailed tags, because they require different knowledge, people should be able to watch and blacklist these topics.

---

I think we can divide `game-engine` questions in 4 main topics, and therefore we could maybe have 4 tags:

1. Making or reverse-engineering game-ready assets for/from game engines
   Questions like specifics of topology and rigging for games, channel-packing, ...
   Tag: `game-ready-assets`
2. Using the BGE
   I know it's dead, but we still see a few questions about it every once in a while. We could just edit the current tag into that one so to keep the assignations and then edit posts as we go.
   Tag: `blender-game-engine`
3. Using Armory/UPBGE or other Blender-based game engines
   I don't know other similar engines, I reckon we could regroup them as one if there's only two? But otherwise we could maybe have distinct tags. But otherwise it's self-explanatory.
   Tag: `armory-upbge`
4. Exporting assets to external game engines like Unity/UE
   I am not so sure either if this one deserves its own tag as it could be part of `game-ready-assets` and we have the `export` tag too, but if tags are a tool for the users to filter questions, follow/blacklist topics, then why not? Let me know.
   Tag: `game-engine-export`

I don't have authority to edit tags (and I wouldn't do so without proper synergy regardless), so if what I spat over here makes sense, "someone else" would have to do it

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a reasonable idea to me!

I've also seen questions like this time and time again and even as a moderator I wasn't sure which category the question should fall into...

I would therefore have the following to say about your suggestions:

1. [game-ready-assets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-ready-assets)

   This tag makes perfect sense to me. It's mostly about questions concerning the export or preparation of geometries and materials, but the topic of game-ready assets usually contains very specific concerns (of course primarily concerning Unity or Unreal Engine), and is therefore certainly worth its own category.
2. [blender-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-game-engine)

   Here I'm not entirely convinced whether an outdated topic deserves its own category. Yes, there are (equally outdated) questions, but this should be tidied up anyway. And as long as BGE is not actively developed further, I see no point in a separate tag.
3. [armory-upbge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armory-upbge)

   To be honest, I don't have enough experience to be able to judge this precisely, but as far as I know there are [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/) and [ARMORY3D](https://armory3d.org/) that would fall into this category. I am generally in favour of using a separate tag here, but it should be more generic and read [upbge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upbge), for example.
4. [game-engine-export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-engine-export)

   The current description for the tag [export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) is:

   > *"Questions involving export-compatibility with other graphics software. Exporting involves converting Blender-native file into an external file type, for the purpose of editing or viewing that file in another program."*

   Here I see more of an overlap with the existing tag for exporting data from Blender. I think here the combination of [game-ready-asset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-ready-asset) and [export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) should be used for a search and no separate tag is needed.

So let's continue the discussion and examine the relevant tags (it should be noted, however, that new tags should save work and make it easier to find answers. Too many tags usually have the opposite effect).

---

To summarise here and to include the comments from [Duarte's post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3056/145249), the following tags are up for debate:

- [game-asset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-asset) (singular)
- [upbge-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upbge-game-engine)
- [blender-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-game-engine)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up, I'm always please to see users other than moderators interested in the meta side of our site.

I share most of the thoughts of Quellenfrom, but I'd add the following.

UPBGE runs inside Blender and may be considered a continuation or spiritual successor of the late Blender game Engine, even if one developed by a third party.

Armory is a third party game engine, that as far as I know (through addons?) provides some editing facilities directly inside Blender, though it is not really an integral part of, or an evolution of deprecated parts of Blender, unlike UPGE.

I think the distinction is important because I would not include *Armory* tags in our site, since I'm inclined to consider it off topic here. I have nothing against Armory, but it seems like a whole large topic on itself, and having the tag here would potentially open a can of worms. It may give the impression that we'd be able to give support here or that third party game engines would be on-topic. I'd give the thought some consideration it if some official developers or knowledgeable members would pledge to be around to provide quality answers, otherwise as far as I know we don't have enough Armory informed users to provide any meaningful support here.

That is to say I'd make an [upbge-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upbge-game-engine) parallel to [blender-game-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-game-engine) but I'd be inclined to exclude any "Armory" mention.

For game asset related assets I'd probably simplify to [game-assets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-assets).

I'm unsure we need a "game-export" dedicated tag, existing [export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) seems to cover it well, as Quellenform mentions, and combined with any new [game-assets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-assets) would suffice to narrow down those topics, I think.

If we do find a need for it, maybe I'd prefer something like [game-engine-io](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-engine-io) (input/output, but maybe we can come up with a clearer name) to cover both imports and exports.

I don't have strong feelings either way, and I'm open to find some consensus.

Comment: Thanks for your expert feedback on this! That would mean that we could consider and discuss the following new tags: [tag:game-assets], [tag:upbge-game-engine], [tag:blender-game-engine], ...if I understand you correctly. The tag [tag:game-engine-io] would rather fall into [tag:game-asset] (in combination with [tag:import]/[tag:export]) from my point of view.

Comment: Yes that is correct, good summary. I'm up for debate though, I confess I'm not very versed about Armory 3D